# How to export function as function expression in express node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a function

```
exports.loginService = async(req,res) => {
  const { workerId, workerPassword } = req.body;
  try {
    const foundUser = await User.findOne({ workerId });
    if (!foundUser) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: "Employee does not exist (Invalid Employee ID)",
      });
    } else if (foundUser.totalLoginAttemptLeft > 0) {
      const { updatedWorker, isMatch } = await checkPassword(
        workerPassword,
        foundUser
      );
      if (!isMatch) {
        passwordNotMatched(res, updatedWorker);
      } else {
        const jwtToken = await totalLogin(foundUser, reset);
        return res.status(200).json({ token: "Bearer " + jwtToken });
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: "You'r account is locked Please contact to ADMIN or HR",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
}
```

I am exporting this in the main route file

```
const loginService = require("../../services/authServices")

router.post("/login", loginService);
```

But when I running the code it's giving this error

> Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object]
> Object

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are exporting an object `{ loginService: [function] }`. When you then import the file, you also get that object. So, access the `loginService` property of the imported variable and you'll get the function. But it would be better to use ES6 imports/exports because it is much clearer and you would not have to do that like written before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the exports object as though it were a function. If you want to **only** export the function, overwrite `exports` rather than assigning to a property on it:

```
module.exports = async(req,res) => {
// ...
};
```

*(Note that it has to be `module.exports`, not just `exports`.)*

**Alternatively**, keep your current export and destructure the `require` call:

```
const { loginService } = require("../../services/authServices");
```

Answer (score 1):

your file exports an object containing a function called `loginService`, so you should do something like:

```
const authServices = require("../../services/authServices")

router.post("/login", authServices.loginService);
```